# I need to append a list from these nested functions in Express but the items will not store

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am dealing with three nested functions and the last one is not returning a list of the items I want. If I log to the console results of the last function from inside the loop I see the URLs I want, but only inside the loop of the function. It does not store them in a list or JSON for anything. It only returns an empty list or empty JSON.

- The first function is just the call to the URL ('/api/getList'), which works fine.
- The second function calls recent posts from a Facebook page. This returns the post ids and I put them into a list just fine.
- The third function is another call to Facebook and it uses the post ids to request the photo URL from said posts. This returns and console logs the URLs but I cannot store them to anything. Strangely, when I console log 'i' in the last function it returns '25' twenty five times. Twenty five is the number of posts, number of image URLs being returned.

*The first function is called once. The second function is called once. The third function is called twenty five times.*

If you're wondering why I have two for loops that should be doing the same thing, it is because I thought this might have solved the problem. I had the same results with one loop.

```
const FB = require('fb')

var image_urls = []
app.get('/api/getList', (req, res1) => {
  FB.api('4300000000643', { fields: 'posts' }, function (res2) {
      if(!res2 || res2.error) {
        console.error(!res2 ? 'error occurred' : res2.error);
        return;
      }
      post_id = res2.posts.data.map(post => post.id)

      for (var i = 0; i < post_id.length; i++) {
        console.log(i)
        FB.api(
          "/"+post_id[i]+"/attachments",
          function (res3) {
            if(!res3 || res3.error) {
              console.error(!res3 ? 'error occurred' : res3.error);
              return;
            }
              // this doesn't seem to do anything
              image_urls.push(res3.data[0].media.image.src)

              // this logs all the URLs I want
              // console.log(res3.data[0].media.image.src)

              // this logs '25' twenty five times for some reason
              console.log(i)                
          }
        );
      }
      // this returns the array of post ids
      console.log(post_id)

      // this returns an empty list
      console.log(image_urls)

    });

  });
```

The 'FB.api' is from the ['NodeJS Library for Facebook'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb)

The `FB.api("/"+post_id[i]+"/attachments",` called in the last function I got from Facebook's documentation [here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-post/attachments/) It doesn't seem to give any information about what kind of function it is exactly.
The Facebook Node package doesn't have any documentation for how query info about individual posts that I've seen.

Coming from Python and being new to Express/ Node, this is really baffling and I'll be interested to learn from you what is going on here.

Comment: What does "I cannot store them to anything" mean?

Comment: I phrased it several different ways just to be clear about it `(res3.data[0].media.image.src)` returns a `[]`, but `console.log(res3.data[0].media.image.src)` in the same spot returns the 25 URLs I want to the log. By 'anything' I mean I've tried. SO wants to know you tried. I can't get them. I need to bring them to the front end.

Comment: You probably want to start simplifying the code a little first: name the vars based on what they contain (e.g. `posts` instead of `res2`, and `images` instead of `res3`), use template strings (similar to python's `f"..."` syntax, except you use backticks rather than quotes, and `${...}` rather than just `{...}`), use `.forEach()` or `.map` on your arrays instead of for-looping, and probably use arrow functions for your callbacks. Also, use `console.error` for errors, rather than `console.log`. None of that solves the problem, but it makes the code _much_ better for getting feedback.

Comment: "posts instead of res2, and images instead of res3". Those are because I have nested functions. Is there a convention for what to name more than one 'response'? I am looking at 'map' now. I've seen it before, but coming from Python I wanted to make things obvious to myself.

Comment: yeah: name them after what they are. You're getting a response, but the response "is" posts data and images data. The fact that it's a response is a given, it's what it represents that matters for keeping code easily readable. (this is as true for Node.js code as it is for Python)

Comment: "it's what it represents that matters for keeping code easily readable." I get most of what you're saying, but not sure I follow this. "console.error for errors, rather than console.log" I'm using console.log for now because that's the only place I can see my results. I'll become the better Node.js programmer you want me to be when I get help figuring out why the URLs can only be seen logged in the console.

Comment: The console has various named logging functions, and the convention is to use the one that reflects the role your log data plays. If you have errors, you log those using `console.error(...)` and if you have expected data, you use `console.log()` (there's also `debug`, `warn`, and `info` - depending on your terminal emulator, those will look different, similar to how they look different when used in the browser)

Comment: I see. Changed that. Changed one of the loops to a map. Turning the last function into a map or forEach instead of a loop would be a little too much for me.

Comment: note that your `post_id` is an array, so you probably want to call that `post_ids`. But, back to the original problem: your `console.log(image_urls)` is _waaaaay_ before your asynchronous functions finish, so the fact that it says `[]` there makes perfect sense. It won't be fully filled until after your last `FB.api` call for the attachment routes finishes, so you'll want to somehow track how many posts need responses, and then how many responses you got. Once there's zero pending, _then_ logging `image_urls` should show a full array.

Comment: Can you update your post to show what FB actually is? (e.g. if that has an async/await or Promise based API, things get a _lot_ easier in terms of "waiting for all the responses to come on")

Comment: I put links where I got these functions from. First FB.api call I got out of a Node package someone made for Facebook. The next time it is called is the same package, but I got the call from the official Facebook docs. Not much description what is going on. Maybe in the docs somewhere I would think. Links provided in the OP. Thank you for the answer. This is new to me and I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Rather than linking, it's easier to say `const FB = require('fb');` in your code. Anyone familiar with node will know that means it's a package you got from the universal package repositories hosted by npm/yarn and we know where to look for additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with asynchronous handling, so you'll have to track how many results you're supposed to get, and only do "what needs to be done with all image urls" once you actually have all of those:

```js
const globalImageList = [];
app.get(`/api/getList`, (req, res) => {
  FB.api(`4300000000643`, { fields: `posts` }, postData => {
    if (!postData || postData.error) {
      console.error(!postData ? `error occurred` : postData.error);
      return res.status(500).write(`server error of some sort`);
    }

    const processList = postData.posts.data.map(post => post.id);
    let resultCount = 0;

    processList.forEach(post_id => {
      FB.api(`/${post_id}/attachments`, imageData => {
        resultCount++;

        if (!imageData || imageData.error) {
          return console.error(!imageData ? `error occurred` : imageData.error);
        }

        const url = imageData.data[0].media.image.src;
        if (url) {
          globalImageList.push(url);
        }

        // Do we have all the images we needed?
        if (resultCount === processList.length) {
          console.log(`Image URLs:`, globalImageList);
          sendImageList(res);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Where `function sendImageList(res)` does whatever you happen to need it to do (send plain text, json, html, xml, etc.).

Also something to consider: don't waste time on refetching the same data, so before you hit `FB.api`, check if `globalImageList` is already filled. If so, immediately `res.write` a response (or whichever API you're using to form well-formed responses that the rest of your code relies on) and return.

Comment: Thank you. Why does `if (resultCount === processList.length)` produce the desired result? There is something about that specific time, (in this case after the 25th string) where what has to have happened? The 'asynchronous' term is confusing. I still have the concept of it fetching all 25 consecutively. I know I could read about it, but I learn best from my problems.

Comment: Also, `sendglobalImageList`. You can just put 'send' in front of a const with no '.'? I got the links through by changing that to `res.send(globalImageList)`. Thanks again for taking pity on me.

Comment: you are running through a list of ids - say there's 50 of them. You _only_ want to form a response once you've processed he 50th one. So that's why we increment `resultCount` for every response (even if it has an error) and we don't do our "final" handling until we've counted 50 results. As for `sendglobalImageList`, I don't understand the question. I'm saying to use a function with that name, because you're going to want to use it in two places: in this code, _and_ and in the code that you're going to write in case the image list is already cached.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it was a function. I'm actually having a lot of problems using the URLs. They only display in my React app if I make them a string with res.text(). I tried making them JSON and mapping with `Object.keys` but that enumerates them for some reason. I actually came here to write a new question about it. You said, "and in the code that you're going to write in". I have the data going into a React client is that where you mean by "write in". This is beyond tutorials I've done. What checks if the image list is chached?

Comment: You do. So you'd start your function as something like `(req, res) => { if(globalImageList.length !== 0) return sendGlobalImageList(res); } ... `